# Changing html form index when a new form element is added

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on an old legacy application which used document.forms[index] approach to access elements in the form and to submit the form. My task is to add a new top panel with few textboxes and buttons. I am using a form for this. This top panel is to be included in all the pages in the application. Now, all the pages stop working since form[index] needs to be updated in all the pages. I know using the form name is the best approach. I have around 1000 places to change. What is the best approach to avoid this problem? I still want to use form for my top panel since I am using spring forms to get the data. Any valuable advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked up the definition of "unmaintainable", that would be a good example.

One trick might be to leave one set of forms, hidden, with the legacy stuff in them, then make another set, lower in the HTML, that the user sees. Then use some JavaScript to map the data back into the original forms in order to continue to work with the expectations of the legacy code. This keeps everything in the same index-order.